# CPU Cycle count as approximation for the number of executed instructions

Tags: windows, profiling, cpu-usage

I am trying to measure CPU cycles spent executing certain code on Windows. While running code above (Visual C++ 11) I've noticed that CPU cycles could significantly vary from run to run. As there is no explicit I/O involved, I don't have a clue why this is happening.

In general what is the relation between CPU cycles spent by the thread and the amount of instructions executed? Can I use CPU cycles as an approximation of that?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned __int64 thread_cycle1;
    unsigned __int64 thread_cycle2;

    HANDLE thread_handle = GetCurrentThread();
    QueryThreadCycleTime(thread_handle, &thread_cycle1);

    // Code for profiling
    int a[] = {1,3,4,5,6,7,23,4,2,6,7,8,9};
    std::sort(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));

    QueryThreadCycleTime(thread_handle, &thread_cycle2);

    std::cout << thread_cycle2 - thread_cycle1 << " cycles";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a large number of factors, some out of your control which may affect your results. ( like cache sizes, hard drive fragmentation state, paging etc.) Further on a preemptive multitasking OS what if the OS interrupts your thread

Comment: According to MSDN, QueryThreadCycleTime includes CPU cycles spent in kernel mode.  When an I/O interrupt occurs, the I/O processing takes place in whatever thread happened to be running at the time.  So the statistics you're gathering may include activity not related to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to generalize too much to be able to say that Cycles ~= # Instructions executed.  Different instructions have different latencies.

You can find details at the following link at least for Intel® 64 and IA-32:

http://www.intel.co.uk/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf

Appendix C goes into such latencies.

As for why they vary, the other comment would apply, especially since cache misses will significantly alter behaviour.